# SumatraPDF landscape layout is cut

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf, printing

I am trying to print the landscape layout from VB.Net page using SumatraPDF, but page gets cut. If I open the SumatraPDF execuytable and print the same page from app, it works great. Here is the command I am using:

```
 Private Sub PrintReport()
    Try
        Dim sPath As String = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath.ToString() + "ReportOutput\"           
        Dim command As String = """" + sPath + "SumatraPDF.exe"" -print-to """ + Me.Printer + """ """ + sPath + Me.Report + """ -print-settings ""fit""  "

        //command looks like:
        //"C:\Dev\Project\ReportOutput\SumatraPDF.exe" -print-to "\\Network\My Printer" "C:\Dev\Project\ReportOutput\card1.pdf" -print-settings "fit"  

        Shell(command)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Logger.LogError(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

It looks like the setting "fit" does not work from the command line. What other options can I try to print PDF document from server side without opening the system print dialog? OR how can I edit the command I use to make it work for the horizontal layout? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/blob/master/src/ParseCommandLine.cpp). On line 128 you have a const with all command line possible value of the parameter.

> ```
> static const char* zoomValues =
> "fit page\0fitpage\0fit-page\0fit width\0fitwidth\0fit-width\0fit "
> "content\0fitcontent\0fit-content\0";
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this doc page](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/docs/Command-line-arguments) you have all command line possible values of the printing parameters. such as   `-print-settings "fit"` and others like "noscale" (ignore internal viewer commands as described in other answer).

What can cause issues is the system default printer orientation (the rotation of paper which must be pre-set by the choice of printer defaults) and the SumatraPDF-settings.txt scalar both have over-riding effects. If device default printer setting is portrait (as many are) and internal Options PrinterDefaults is left at "shrink"

```
PrinterDefaults [
    PrintScale = none
]
```

the result of auto-rotation may  not be as expected. Thus do not take Landscape and Portrait at face value, use as tested, so if rotation using ",landscape" word is wrong test-out by forcing ",portrait" rotation.

SumatraPDF depends entirely on Windows Print as Image settings, so its possible to alter settings for custom paper shapes sizes and layouts in Windows Print Server panels but SumatraPDF can only use those that have a correct Windows allocated media "named variable" or "paperkind" number (often around 256 or there about).